# ESP8266 and Arduino - SoftwareSerial vs Serial problem

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm using Arduino Nano and ESP8266.

When I setup like the picture and connect Arduino Nano to PC by USB: [image]

The ESP8266 properly works. (Arduino Nano is just used as a bridge)

I print and read from serial with a C# program, it correctly works.

What I send from C# program:

```
AT+CWJAP="APN", "Pass"
```

The message from ESP:

```
AT+CWJAP="APN", "Pass"
OK
```

But, when I change the setup as follows:

- Green wire (green wire on picture) to Arduino Digital2 pin
- Red wire (red wire on picture) to Arduino Digital3 pin
- Use Arduino code to read/write serial, instead of C# program
- Create a software serial from code (esp8266 = SoftwareSerial(2, 3))

What I send from SoftwareSerial:

```
AT+CWJAP="APN", "Pass"
```

The message from ESP:

```
AT+CWJAP="APN", "Pass"
ERROR
```

Do you have any ideas? Why isn't the result on SoftwareSerial identical to Serial?

Comment: What does "Green wire to D2" mean precisely? Ditto "Red wire to D3" - if these are components then explain where they are and what they do.

Comment: The green wire on picture (the wire that I previously connected to RX), and the red wire on picture (the wire that I previously connected to TX).

Comment: D2, D3 - are these diodes dude?

Comment: Arduino Digital2 pin, Arduino Digital3 pin

Comment: Totally off topic but have you considered using ESP as the arduino itself? You can use ESP-07 or ESP12 to get more GPIO pins and you can directly program the ESP using Arduino IDE. [Here is more info on that topic](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino).

Answer (score 1):

This is the info taken from [arduino website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial):

The library has the following known limitations:

1) If using multiple software serial ports, only one can receive data at a time.

2) Not all pins on the Leonardo and Micro support change interrupts, so only the following can be used for RX: 8, 9, 10, 11, 14 (MISO), 15 (SCK), 16 (MOSI).

This has not explicitly mentioned the board you are using, but I think these limitations are on hardware level. Changing the software serial pins should most likely take care of this issue.